# Given 3D edge points How to generate mesh

Tags: python, c++

I have a set of 3D edge points, and I want to create a surface. Because the points are 3D, I cannot use Delaunay triangulation. And I don't know how to use 3D B-Spline surface and how to convert it to mesh. Is there any python/c++ lib or any algorithm for this problem?

Comment: You need to define some measure of what you regard as surface of the thing.

Comment: Maybe http://pointclouds.org/ ?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't know what the measure you mean. Could you give some introduction to it?

Comment: @Sergey Thank you. I will go and take a look of it.

Comment: @cbjcbj: Let's say all your points except three are on the surface of a sphere. The three points are close to the center. If you don't want the sphere surface triangulation to include those three points, then there needs to be some way for the algorithm to decide to not include them.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So do you mean I should know in advance the shape of the surface? If I already know the points are on the surface of the sphere, how can I detect the radius and generate the mesh?